# How to detect from where 404 error is coming? debugger calls the method and works fine but then stills it showing 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

```
package com.crudoperation;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String helloGfg() {
        return "hii";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/showEmployee";
    }
}
```

debugger comes in helloGfg method but then it still showing 404 error..i think there will be some other dependency or annotaion based issues......how could i find the issue?below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.crudoperation</groupId>
    <artifactId>crudoperation</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crudoperation Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.version>5.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.51</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>crudoperation</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

how to find from where the error is coming..in maven project in webapp directory  when i seperately run as run on server then it did not even find seprate file..how to solve it?

[image]

this is my project structure..which thing i need to remove.i cannot understand.

here is the code for viewResolver

```
  package com.crudoperation;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
    import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.crudoperation")
    public class EmployeeAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }
    
    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's own
        // resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
        // templates to be automatically updated when modified.
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }
    
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry resourceHandlerRegistry) {
            resourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you call? how do you call it? do you have error logs?

Comment: As you are not using Spring boot, you will have to explicitly declare `ViewResolver`. If you have already declared it, please post that code too.

Comment: yes,i have added it..now it is working for .jsp file but for .html file it is still showing 404 error @ChetanAhirrao

Comment: i am calling controller  with ("/) requestmapping which is works well for .jsp file after adding viewResolver but it does not work and give 404 error for .html file @Stultuske

Answer (score 3):

Try to define in `webapp` folder a `hii.html` file. `helloGfg` is returning `hii` but the resource with such name is missing.

Comment: even hii.html  still not found after creating hii.html in webapp folder @artiomi

Comment: can you try to define a template resolver as per this [link](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect)

Comment: yes i have created hii1.html file in web-inf/template folder but it gives error like :
Message JSP file [/WEB-INF/views/hii1.jsp] not found,it its still searhing for jsp file..i have added code as per the link @artiomi and when i comment InternalViewResolver it gives error as: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: Try to move .jsp and .html files to `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views`

Comment: tried it...for .html file it is still not working

Comment: Hmm, can you have a look at this [example](https://www.studytonight.com/spring-framework/spring-mvc-with-thymeleaf)

Comment: tried it..it shows different error message: @artiomi error message is:java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/newFile.html]
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:158)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248589/discussion-between-artiomi-and-ritu-mansata).

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have both the `ViewResolver` in place, you can add/set Order to them. Try,

```
    templateResolver.setOrder(0); //or lower value
```

Comment: yes,but now  i am getting another exception.exception is :java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/newFile.html]

Comment: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/newFile.html]")

Comment: Did you also set order for `InternalResourceViewResolver`. Set it to higher value i.e. say setOrder(1)

Comment: and Try  `templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/WEB-INF/templates/");`

Comment: finally solved "org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "hii1", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers by adding randomfile.html to views folder and solved other issue by adding thymeleaf-spring3 maven dependency instead of thymeleaf-spring5  .. @Chetan Ahirrao

Answer (score 0):

first I have to add

```
package com.crudoperation;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring3.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.crudoperation")
@Qualifier(value = "EmployeeAppConfig")
public class EmployeeAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry resourceHandlerRegistry) {
        resourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver yourTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver configurer = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        configurer.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        configurer.setSuffix(".html");
        configurer.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        configurer.setOrder(0); // this is important. This way spring //boot will listen to both places 0 and 1
        configurer.setCacheable(false);
        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver srtr = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        srtr.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        srtr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        srtr.setSuffix(".html");

        return srtr;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

so that path can be found